# Hello. How to display 100 results on the page https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, steam

I want to make an extension so that the search page displays 100 results, but I don’t know how to do it. I started to take apart the Steam Treid Helper and came across 2 great functions:

```
g_oSearchResults.m_cPageSize = 100; 
g_oSearchResults.GoToPage(0, true);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Steam Market Api uses the following endpoint

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=10&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&appid=730
```

The response contains a `results_html` key which has the partial html for the new page.

You can use `start` and `count` (set this to 100 for your usecase) query parameters to fetch the required html and manually replace the dom with the new data using your extension.

Remember to pass in your login cookie in the headers aswell.
(You can use the Chrome/Firefox network inspector tab to get the correct request schema)